# Jquery: When div is visible and input is empty, disable button

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup

I have a form wizard and I want to check it. The button next is outside of the div, the form is in 3 steps:

```
<div id="step1"> Inputs </div>
<div id="step2"> Inputs </div>
<div id="step3"> Inputs </div>
```

I tried to check in this way:

```
$('#title').keyup(function() {
    if ($('#step-22').is(':visible')) {

        if ($(this).val().length <= 0) {
            $('.buttonNext').hide();
        } else {
            $('.buttonNext').show();
        }
    }
    else {
        $('.buttonNext').show();
    }
}).keyup();
```

This Work in all the steps, but i need this only in step1...It's an IF issues?

Create a snippet is a little difficult, in this link you can see the example: https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/form_wizards.html

Comment: question is unclear.create an example link (with dummy data no problem), so that we can understood and help you

Comment: `if ($('#step-22').is(':visible') && $(this).is(":empty"))`

Comment: Please add the missing code so we can replicate the problem. More `HTML` please...and maybe some `CSS` too.

Comment: Hi Mohammad, thanks for your answer but doesn't work

Comment: surely if you are binding to a keyup, then the input should be visible?